# is there a way to do "saypx" in cuBLAS?

Tags: cuda, cublas

cublasSaxpy computes y' = a * x + y, where x and y are vectors and a is scalar.

It turns out I need to compute y' = a * y + x instead. I'm not seeing how to twist the cuBLAS library into doing that.

(Of course, I could compute y' = a * y, then y' = y' + x, but y' is read too often in that case. And I could write my own CUDA code to do it, but then it's likely not anywhere near as fast as the cuBLAS code. I'm just surprised there's no apparent way to do "saypx" directly.)

[Added] There are functions similar to "saxpby" in Intel's version of cblas, which would do what I need. But oddly enough, that's not in cuBLAS.

[Added #2] It looks like I can use the cudnnAddTensor function, with some aliasing of descriptors (I have a FilterDescriptor that points to the tensor, which AddTensor won't accept, but I should be able to alias a TensorDescriptor to the same memory and shape.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way I am aware of to do what you are asking in CUBLAS, nor in standard BLAS. What you have found in MKL is an extension added by Intel, but I don't recall seeing something similar in other host and accelerator BLAS implementations.

The good news is that your assertion that "I could write my own CUDA code to do it, but then it's likely not anywhere near as fast as the cuBLAS code", is untrue, at least for an operation as trivial as saxpy. Even a naïve implementation of saxpy will get very close to CUBLAS because there really aren't that many was to read two arrays, perform an FMAD and write back the result. As long as you get memory coalescing correct, it is pretty simple to write performant code. For example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

#include "cublas_v2.h"

typedef enum
{ 
    AXPY = 0,
    AXPBY = 1
} saxpy_op_t;

__device__ __host__ __inline__ 
float axpby_op(float y, float x, float a)
{
    return a * y + x;
}

__device__ __host__ __inline__ 
float axpy_op(float y, float x, float a)
{
    return y + a * x;
}

template<typename T>
class pitched_accessor
{
    T * p;
    size_t pitch;

    public:
    __host__ __device__
    pitched_accessor(T *p_, size_t pitch_) : p(p_), pitch(pitch_) {};

    __host__ __device__
    T& operator[](size_t idx) { return p[pitch*idx]; };

    __host__ __device__ 
    const T& operator[](size_t idx) const { return p[pitch*idx]; };
};


template<saxpy_op_t op>
__global__ 
void saxpy_kernel(pitched_accessor<float> y, pitched_accessor<float> x, 
                  const float a, const unsigned int N1)
{
    unsigned int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    unsigned int stride = gridDim.x * blockDim.x;

    #pragma unroll 8
    for(; idx < N1; idx += stride) {
        switch (op) {
            case AXPY:
                y[idx] = axpy_op(y[idx], x[idx], a);
                break;
            case AXPBY:
                y[idx] = axpby_op(y[idx], x[idx], a);
                break;
        }
    }
}

__host__ void saxby(const unsigned int N, const float a, 
                    float *x, int xinc, float *y, int yinc)
{
    int gridsize, blocksize;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&gridsize, &blocksize, saxpy_kernel<AXPBY>);
    saxpy_kernel<AXPBY><<<gridsize, blocksize>>>(pitched_accessor<float>(y, yinc), 
                                                 pitched_accessor<float>(x, xinc), a, N);
}

__host__ void saxpy(const unsigned int N, const float a, 
                    float *x, int xinc, float *y, int yinc)
{
    int gridsize, blocksize;
    cudaOccupancyMaxPotentialBlockSize(&gridsize, &blocksize, saxpy_kernel<AXPY>);
    saxpy_kernel<AXPY><<<gridsize, blocksize>>>(pitched_accessor<float>(y, yinc), 
                                                pitched_accessor<float>(x, xinc), a, N);
}

void check_result(std::vector<float> &yhat, float result, float tolerance=1e-5f)
{
    auto it = yhat.begin();
    for(; it != yhat.end(); ++it) {
        float err = std::fabs(*it - result);
        assert( err < tolerance ); 
    }
}

int main()
{

    const int N = 1<<22;

    std::vector<float> x_h(N);
    std::vector<float> y_h(N);

    const float a = 2.f, y0 = 1234.f, x0 = 532.f;
    std::fill(y_h.begin(), y_h.end(), y0);
    std::fill(x_h.begin(), x_h.end(), x0);

    float *x_d, *y_d;
    size_t sz = sizeof(float) * size_t(N);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&x_d, sz);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&y_d, sz);

    cudaMemcpy(x_d, &x_h[0], sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    {
        cudaMemcpy(y_d, &y_h[0], sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        saxby(N, a, x_d, 1, y_d, 1);
        std::vector<float> yhat(N);
        cudaMemcpy(&yhat[0], y_d, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        check_result(yhat, axpby_op(y0, x0, a));
    }

    {
        cudaMemcpy(y_d, &y_h[0], sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        saxpy(N, a, x_d, 1, y_d, 1);
        std::vector<float> yhat(N);
        cudaMemcpy(&yhat[0], y_d, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        check_result(yhat, axpy_op(y0, x0, a));
    }

    {
        cublasHandle_t handle;
        cublasCreate(&handle);
        cudaMemcpy(y_d, &y_h[0], sz, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cublasSaxpy(handle, N, &a, x_d, 1, y_d, 1);
        std::vector<float> yhat(N);
        cudaMemcpy(&yhat[0], y_d, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        check_result(yhat, axpy_op(y0, x0, a));
        cublasDestroy(handle);
    }

    return int(cudaDeviceReset());
}
```

This demonstrates that a very simple axpy kernel can be easily adapted to perform both the standard operation and the version you want, and run within 10% of the runtime of CUBLAS on the compute 5.2 device I tested it on:

```
$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 -Xptxas="-v" -o saxby saxby.cu -lcublas
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z12saxpy_kernelIL10saxpy_op_t0EEv16pitched_accessorIfES2_fj' for 'sm_52'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z12saxpy_kernelIL10saxpy_op_t0EEv16pitched_accessorIfES2_fj
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 17 registers, 360 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function '_Z12saxpy_kernelIL10saxpy_op_t1EEv16pitched_accessorIfES2_fj' for 'sm_52'
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z12saxpy_kernelIL10saxpy_op_t1EEv16pitched_accessorIfES2_fj
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 17 registers, 360 bytes cmem[0]

$ nvprof ./saxby
==26806== NVPROF is profiling process 26806, command: ./saxby
==26806== Profiling application: ./saxby
==26806== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 54.06%  11.190ms         5  2.2381ms     960ns  2.9094ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
 40.89%  8.4641ms         3  2.8214ms  2.8039ms  2.8310ms  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
  1.73%  357.59us         1  357.59us  357.59us  357.59us  void saxpy_kernel<saxpy_op_t=1>(pitched_accessor<float>, pitched_accessor<float>, float, unsigned int)
  1.72%  355.15us         1  355.15us  355.15us  355.15us  void saxpy_kernel<saxpy_op_t=0>(pitched_accessor<float>, pitched_accessor<float>, float, unsigned int)
  1.60%  332.21us         1  332.21us  332.21us  332.21us  void axpy_kernel_val<float, int=0>(cublasAxpyParamsVal<float>)
```

Comment: Okay. Also, thanks for the excellent short tutorial on how to write CUDA code and profile it under linux! (The Windows structure is much more complex.)
I wonder if using fmad() would take care of the last 10%.